# Mongoose returns documents inside model object

Tags: mongoose

whenever I console log a created document, or when I query it, even with .require() I just get too much stuff returned. It looks like the documents are returned inside the model object.

I have minized my code to the minimum.

```
/* jshint  esversion: 8 */                                                                                   

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/freecodecamp-learning-mongoose')
  .then (()=> console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to mongoDB', err));

const Schema1 = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
});

const DocumentModel = mongoose.model('Document',Schema1);

async function createDocument(){
  const document = new DocumentModel({
    name: 'document name'
  });
  const result = await document.save();
  console.log(result);
}

createDocument();


async function getAllDocuments(){
  const documents = await DocumentModel.find().select({name:1});//.count();
console.log(documents);
}

// getAllDocuments();
```

this is what I get if I execute it... even if i query with .select()

```
model {
  '$__': InternalCache {
    strictMode: true,
    selected: undefined,
    shardval: undefined,
    saveError: undefined,
    validationError: undefined,
    adhocPaths: undefined,
    removing: undefined,
    inserting: true,
    version: undefined,
    getters: {},
    _id: 5ce11d9cf5675b6482d0fa38,
    populate: undefined,
    populated: undefined,
    wasPopulated: false,
    scope: undefined,
    activePaths: StateMachine {
      paths: {},
      states: [Object],
      stateNames: [Array],
      map: [Function]
    },
    pathsToScopes: {},
    ownerDocument: undefined,
    fullPath: undefined,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: 0
    },
    '$options': true
  },
  isNew: false,
  errors: undefined,
  _doc: { _id: 5ce11d9cf5675b6482d0fa38, name: 'document name', __v: 0 }
```

the queries themselves work fine, and even If I query for a .count() I would get the right amount (in this case 1).

Answer (score 4):

Mongoose queries return instance of the Mongoose Document Class. You need to use `lean` in order to avoid the instance of the Document Class.
Use the following code inside your `getAllDocuments` function:

```
const documents = await DocumentModel.find().select({name:1}).lean()
```

Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html#using-lean